# Enabling emails in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have enabled the email notification in apache superset by setting the below flag to true :

```
ENABLE_SCHEDULED_EMAIL_REPORTS = True
```

But now i am getting the below error while creating the scheduled reports :

> NoneType object has no attribute 'split'

Can anyone please guide ?

Comment: This must have to do something with your data. Kindly recheck the data and ensure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

once you're done with setting:

```
ENABLE_SCHEDULED_EMAIL_REPORTS = True
```

you need to reinitialize the superset using the command:

```
superset init
```

This should mostly work.